# What is the most attractive number less that 100?

Tags: applications, numbering

I hope this is the correct forum for this question. I have an app that I am planning on releasing to app store. I'm trying to decide how to price the app. And I was thinking that aesthetically perhaps there is a number that is most appealing ? Perhaps users don;t consciously think of this when buying an app and all they are concerned with is the actual price. I've read that .99 versus 1 is makes a big difference when consumers are deciding wether or not to purchase. Or maybe I am just over thinking this and should just go with what I feel its worth.

Comment: Isn't that heavily dependent upon the font the number is displayed in?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not relate to design in any form. There is a psychological reason 99¢ seems more appealing than $1, but this isn't a psychology SE site. I do not see how your product pricing relates to design.

Comment: You'd be best off finding a site used by marketing experts or about advice for startups, this isn't part of a designer's expertise. (also, don't forget that even if you find the perfect number, app stores are international - so the majority of would-be customers will see a different auto-converted number in their own currency).

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, and based on my experience with appstore the best attractive number there is 0 - absolute zero.

The only chance you have to sell any app now - are in-app purchases, so if you don't have thousands of dollars to promote your app, then set its price to 0.

Want to sell it with any other price? It does not matter - it will fail without promotion.

Comment: This is a valid point. Most successful apps these days go the [Freemium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) route. Use the free users to build up the buzz and if it is a hit, they will do the marketing for you. @user470184